# Digit Grouping in String

Tags: javascript

So, I want to write a gex that will capture string in a string in a group of 3's but if the remaining characters length is not divisible by 3 they should be grouped in 2's.

Examples:

- `123456` should be `123 456`
- `1234567891011` should be `123 456 789 10 11`

Can someone help me please?

I have tried (.{1,3})(.{3}|.{2}) but it doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 0):

You could take a positive lookahead for two characters.

```js
const format = string => string.replace(/.{2,3}(?=..)/g, '$& ')

console.log(['12', '123', '1234', '12345', '123456', '1234567', '12345678', '123456789', '1234567890'].map(format));
```

Comment: sorry, i have no idea of ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
(?=\d{5})(\d{3})|(\d{2})
```

https://regex101.com/r/qrrB7O/1

Explanation:

1. (?=\d{5}) - positive lookahead, matches as long as there are 5 digits left at the end of the string.
2. (?=\d{5})(\d{3}) - when there are five digits left at the end of the string, create groups of three numbers.
3. |(\d{2}) otherwise, create groups of two numbers.

Comment: It doesn't work for the strings with the `length % 3 == 0`. 
`123`, `123456`, etc.